# Calculating p-values for categorical variables in R, some results are showing a zero. What does this mean?

Tags: r, regression, p-value

I am calculating the p-values of categorical variables in R for a multinomial logisitic regression.

How do I interpret the result of VEHICLE_TYPE6, VEHICLE_TYPE7, and VEHICLE_TYPE8? The output is a single digit zero...seems a bit odd...not sure if it's telling me that the result is highly significant or perhaps some type of error. Can anyone help?

```
> p_values <- (1 - pnorm(abs(z_stats)))*2
> p_values
  (Intercept) SURFACE_COND2 SURFACE_COND3 SURFACE_COND4 SURFACE_COND5 SURFACE_COND9 VEHICLE_TYPE2 VEHICLE_TYPE3
2           0  1.732286e-08     0.1979489  7.654519e-07  1.634368e-02  7.505911e-03  3.917932e-04   0.024577610
3           0  4.137271e-07     0.1505311  0.000000e+00  1.776133e-10  3.497501e-05  1.126374e-05   0.001057668
  VEHICLE_TYPE4 VEHICLE_TYPE5 VEHICLE_TYPE6 VEHICLE_TYPE7 VEHICLE_TYPE8 VEHICLE_TYPE9 VEHICLE_TYPE10 VEHICLE_TYPE11
2     0.1873876  6.542883e-04             0             0             0  1.866588e-08   1.678066e-01     0.02322403
3     0.1458607  7.277671e-05             0             0             0  4.074296e-12   5.167644e-09     0.01476668
```

Comment: If your z statistics are >= 9 then it will be (practically) zero.

Comment: @user2974951 should those levels be excluded from from my analysis? Are the statistically significant or insignificant?

Comment: You should absolutely NOT exclude variables. If the effect is so strong that the p-value is 0 then this is very statistically significant, it is what it is.